How do i style react-native-maps MapView component in expo for IOS
I'm working on a map feature in my React Native app using Expo (SDK v51). I previously used Google Maps for both Android and iOS, where I could apply custom map styles (e.g., dark mode). However, with the recent update, Expo now defaults to Apple Maps on iOS, and it seems that react-native-maps doesn't support styling Apple Maps the way it does Google Maps.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
<MapView
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  ref={mapRef}
  style={styles.map}
  region={region}
  onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChange}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  customMapStyle={currentTheme === "dark" ? darkMapStyle : []}
/>

With Google Maps, I could use customMapStyle to apply a JSON-based style, like darkMapStyle, to the map. Unfortunately, this doesn’t work for Apple Maps.
My Question
Is there any way to apply custom styles (like dark mode) to Apple Maps in React Native using react-native-maps or any other approach compatible with Expo? If not, are there any known workarounds to achieve similar results with Apple Maps?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Environment:

Expo SDK: 51
React Native: 0.72
react-native-maps version:1.14.0
Platforms: iOS

Thank you!

Could you please check this if it's helpful?
